# CI/CD Pipeline Azure Devops

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, expo, continuous-deployment, yarnpkg

I want to automate the build apk process using azure devops.
I am trying to integrate azure devops CI/CD pipeline in my expo project with yarn.
I have created build pipeline but i am not able to create release pipeline.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your requirement?

Comment: Please share more info ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the link with video and documentation how to crate release pipeline
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you publish the build Artifacts in the build pipeline so that the files are available in the Release pipeline. To create a release pipeline you will have to add install Google Play from the marketplace and then install the *Google Play - Release* or *Google Play - Relase Bundle* depending on if you have built .apk or .aab. In the task you will have to setup a Service Connection by going to the Google Play store and creating a service account and then copying the credentials back to the Service Connection.

It's a long process and I have created a comprehensive article specifically for that purpose. Here is the [link](https://arjavdave.com/2021/03/16/how-to-setup-ci-cd-pipelines-for-android-with-azure-devops/#deployment-task).